# Limiting/Aggregating Results When Selecting on an ID followed by a CASE

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Trying to pull some data from a Log table.

Simplified version of the query I'm using below:

```
SELECT
    type_id AS type_id
    , CASE WHEN LogOperation = 'Insert' THEN CreateDT ELSE NULL END AS create_date
    , CASE WHEN (AuditID > 0 OR AuditID IS NOT NULL) AND OldVal_AuditID IS NULL THEN LogTimeStamp ELSE NULL END AS audit_date
FROM TypeLOG
ORDER BY type_id
```

Sample result set:

```
|---------|-------------|------------|
| type_id | create_date | audit_date |
|---------|-------------|------------|
| 176     | 2019-06-01  | NULL       |
| 177     | 2019-06-01  | NULL       |
| 177     | NULL        | 2019-06-03 |
| 178     | 2019-06-03  | NULL       |
| 178     | NULL        | 2019-06-04 |
| 178     | NULL        | NULL       |
```

How could I pull this data so only 1 row per type_id is shown? This is a log table so naturally other operations such as updates and deletes create multiple rows per type_id.

Related to this, there can theoretically be multiple 'Inserts' per type_id... I would want the first 'Insert' per type_id, I suppose based on the earliest LogTimeStamp.

How do I need to modify my query to reflect this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta do the CTE's or self joins it should look like that

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT TYPE_ID,
       CASE WHEN LogOperation = 'Insert' THEN CreateDT ELSE NULL END AS create_date
FROM TypeLOG
), CTE2 (
SELECT TYPE_ID,
       CASE WHEN (AuditID > 0 OR AuditID IS NOT NULL) AND OldVal_AuditID IS NULL THEN LogTimeStamp ELSE NULL END AS audit_date
FROM TypeLOG
)
    SELECT CTE1.TYPE_ID, CREATE_DATE, AUDIT_DATE
    FROM CTE1 JOIN CTE2 
    ON CTE1.TYPE_ID = CTE2.TYPE_ID
    ORDER BY TYPE_ID
```